# How to delete mirrored values in 2 columns

Tags: psql

I have a table with 2 columns that contain some rows with unique id pairs and some rows with pairs that are a mirrored duplicate of another row. I want to remove one of the duplicates.

```
 id1 | id2 
-----+-----
   1 |   9
   2 |  10
   5 |   4
   6 |  16
   7 |  11
   8 |  12
   9 |   1
  10 |   2
  12 |  14
  14 |   8
  16 |   6
```

So `1 | 9` mirrors `9 | 1`. I want to keep `1 | 9` but delete `9 | 1`.

I've tried.

```
    SELECT
        id1,
        id2
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            id1, id2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id1, id2 ORDER BY id1) AS occu
        FROM
            table
        ) t
    WHERE
        t.occu = 1;
```

But it has no effect.

I'm pretty new to this so any help you can give would be greatly appreciated.

====UPDATE====

I accepted the answer from @Mureinik and adapted it to work as a filter in a subquery:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table
WHERE
    id1 NOT IN (SELECT
                    id1
                FROM
                    table a
                WHERE
                    id1 > id2
                    AND
                    EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM table b
                            WHERE a.id1 = b.id2 AND a.id2 = b.id1));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could arbitrarily decide to keep the rows where `id1 < id2`, and use an `exists` clause to find their counterparts:

```
DELETE FROM myable a
WHERE  id1 > id2 AND
       EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   mytable b
               WHERE  a.id1 = b.id2 AND a.id2 = b.id1)
```